# Using multi-threading / parallel to find a working port

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a function like below to connect to an FTP which port keeps changing

```
private int FindWorkingPort(int from, int to)
{
    for (int port = from; port <= to; port++)
    {
        try
        {
            new FtpClient(_host, port).Connect();  // Instant on correct port, very slow on wrong port
            return port;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    throw new Exception("None of the port is working");
}
```

When the first try was correct, it is instant. Otherwise, each try can take 10 seconds. You can imagine if the correct one is the last one.

Is there any way to make it try all possible ports at the same time? (I'm noob in multi-threading)

**EDIT:**

I'm using [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) that does have `.ConnectAsync()`

Comment: 1) What is `FtpClient`? 2) Usually, you can reduce timeout value, but this will produce wrong results, if there is actually timeout issue 3) If `FtpClient` has async API, you can try parallelize connection requests, but this can be limited due to your network infrastructure, as well as host network infrastructure. In other words, there can't be 100% effective and robust solution. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Dennis. 1) FluentFTP  2) You're right thanks, so it's still better if it can check a few ports at the same time  3) It does support async. I'm not sure how the host will handle multiple connections if that's what your saying. What I'm trying to achieve is to find the working port faster

Comment: @Aximili you can try to *telnet* to the port instead of establishing a connection.

Comment: Please don't ever to `try { ... } catch { }` - it's a bad anti-pattern. You should only ever catch **specific** exceptions that you can **meaningfully** handle. Also, don't throw exceptions when nothing exceptional happened.

Comment: this may (or rather should) trigger port scanning alerts on the target network.

Comment: It's also possible that your IP gets blocked when you're trying to open many connections in a given time frame.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks, but I couldn't find any C# example on that. Any link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try connecting to all the ports simultaneously with multiple threads however the performance will degrade as more threads start. I'll suggest you try with Task.

Here is an example with Task and Event. It's not exactly the solution but you will get the gist with this. You may have to change your code structure.

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class Program
    {
        public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
             public int port {get; set; }

             public MyEventArgs(int port)
             {
                 this.port = port;
             }
        }

        delegate void OpenPort(object sender, MyEventArgs  e);
        event OpenPort OnOpen;
        int from = 10, to = 20;
        int Connected = 16;

        public static void Main()
        {
            var obj = new Program();
            // here you register your method ShowPort for OnOpen event. 
            obj.OnOpen += new OpenPort(ShowPort);
            for(int i = obj.from; i < obj.to; i++) {
                obj.CheckPort(obj, i);
            }
        }

       private async void CheckPort(Program obj, int i) 
       {
           await CheckPortTask(obj, i);
       }

       private Task CheckPortTask(Program obj, int i)
       {
             return Task.Run(() =>  {
                if(i == obj.Connected)
                {
                  obj.OnOpen(this, new MyEventArgs(i));
                }
         });
       }            

        // This method will be called after connecting.
        public static void ShowPort(Object p, MyEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.port);
        }
    }
```

If you want to try with thread then replace the Task.Run block in the above code with this:

```
new Thread(()=>{
                        if(i == obj.w) 
                        {
                            // this raises the event and calls the ShowPort method.
                            obj.OnOpen(obj, new MyEventArgs(i));
                        }
                    })).Start();
```

Comment: Tasks use threads too. *This* code will exit before even one connection request returns though - you forgot to await the tasks

Answer (score 0):

Here is not the best, but working solution:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(from, to - from).ToList().Select(port => {
    try
    {
        return new FtpClient(_host, port).ConnectAsync().ContinueWith(_ => (int?)port);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Task.FromResult((int?)null);
    }
});
var foundPort = (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);
```

Basically you create a list of all ports you want to check and start a task for each one of them. You wait till all of them finish asynchronously and get the first one that is not `null`. All tasks will run in parallel, but `await Task.WhenAll` will wait for all of them to finish which means that it will always wait ~10 seconds(according to your question, checking incorrect port usually takes ~10 seconds).

This could probably be improved with `Task.WhenAny`, but returning correct port is tricky when other tasks throw exceptions.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks FCin for the explanation. So if the first one is correct (which I hope is the case most of the time) using WhenAll will only make it worse. And I don't know how to do .WhenAny(tasks where result != null)

Comment: @Aximili Correct, if you have to check 2-3 ports then it is probably not worth it, but if you have to check >10 then it becomes useful, because wait time here is constant. I will play with it more and maybe find a way to do `Task.WhenAny`. This way you should get result instantly all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. This should return immediately when the first valid task completes:

```
public async Task<int> FindWorkingPortAsync(int from, int to)
{
    var wrapper = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(from, to - from).ToList().Select(port =>
    {
        return new FtpClient(_host, port).ConnectAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            try
            {
                if(!wrapper.Task.IsCompleted && !t.IsFaulted && !t.IsCanceled)
                    wrapper.SetResult(port);
                return t;
            }
            catch
            {
                return Task.FromResult(-1);
            }
        });
    }).ToList();


    return await wrapper.Task;
}
```

Let me know if it works. I tested it with `HttpClient` instead of `FtpClient`.